# How to give V-model to elements

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have dynamically creating input fields from JSON data using vue.js. The issue I am facing I to give them dynamic v-model

**What I am doing is**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      totalAmt: 500,
      paymentMode: [{
        "PAYMENTCODE": "SW",
        "PAYMENTNAME": "Swiggy"
      }, {
        "PAYMENTCODE": "BB",
        "PAYMENTNAME": "uber Eats"
      }, {
        "PAYMENTCODE": "WE",
        "PAYMENTNAME": "Zomato"
      }]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    balAmt() {
      return 0 - this.totalAmt
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <label>Total Amt</label>
    <input type="text" v-model="totalAmt">
  </div>
  <div v-for="mode in paymentMode" :key="mode.PAYMENTCODE" class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
    <label>{{mode.PAYMENTNAME}}</label>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Bal Amt</label>
    <input type="text" :value="balAmt">
  </div>
</div>
```

**What I am trying to do is:**

Two fields `Total Amt` and `Bal Amt` I have in total amount there is some value and in Bal Amt, I have the same value of total amt but as -  like `Total Amt=500` then `Bal-Amt=-500` this is when page loads

Now there are some dynamic input field here there are three, so when I type suppose 50 in one `input field` say as in `Swiggy` I want to do `500-50` i.e `Total Amt-the field amount`

For static fields, I can easily do this but here I am having dynamic fields how can I do this.

Comment: i have readed carefully and i still cant figure out what you want to archive

Comment: You can add a `v-model="mode.Amount"` to the input. It will add an `Amount` property to each object in `paymentMode`. It's not clear where you want to show the `500-50`

Comment: @adiga `500-50` to bal amount look it is -500 initially so when i enter something in input field i have to do `500-50(or what ever entered)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to `totalAmt`, add a `v-model` to each input and set it to `"mode.Amount"`. Then inside `balAmt`, calculate the sum of each input and subtract it from `totalAmt`

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      totalAmt: 500,
      paymentMode: [{
        "PAYMENTCODE": "SW",
        "PAYMENTNAME": "Swiggy"
      }, {
        "PAYMENTCODE": "BB",
        "PAYMENTNAME": "uber Eats"
      }, {
        "PAYMENTCODE": "WE",
        "PAYMENTNAME": "Zomato"
      }]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    balAmt() {
      // sum of inputs of paymentMode
      const sum = this.paymentMode.reduce((a, b) => a + (+b.Amount || 0), 0);
      return sum - this.totalAmt;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <label>Total Amt</label>
    <input type="text" v-model="totalAmt">
  </div>
  <div v-for="mode in paymentMode" :key="mode.PAYMENTCODE" class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
    <label>{{mode.PAYMENTNAME}}</label>
    <input type="text" v-model="mode.Amount">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Bal Amt</label>
    <input type="text" :value="balAmt">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hey bal amount should be in negative initially

Comment: @manishthakur that behavior is not consistent. What if I type 50 in the field and `balAmt` becomes `450` not `-450`. And I remove the amount, it should become `-500`?

Comment: by changing `return sum - this.totalAmt;` like this it is doing fine

Comment: Hey here in `swiggy` input field what I am trying to do is it should not allow greater than Total Amt like, If `total Amt=500` then `swiggy should always be 500 not 501`, Please give me some idea to do that

Answer (score 1):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      totalAmt: 500,
      paymentMode: [{
        "PAYMENTCODE": "SW",
        "PAYMENTNAME": "Swiggy",
        amount: 0
      }, {
        "PAYMENTCODE": "BB",
        "PAYMENTNAME": "uber Eats",
        amount: 0,
      }, {
        "PAYMENTCODE": "WE",
        "PAYMENTNAME": "Zomato",
        amount: 0
      }]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    otherAmt() {
      let amt = 0
      this.paymentMode.forEach(mode => {
        amt += Number(mode.amount)
      })
      return amt
    },
    balAmt() {
      return 0 - (this.totalAmt - this.otherAmt)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <label>Total Amt</label>
    <input type="text" v-model="totalAmt">
  </div>
  <div v-for="mode in paymentMode" :key="mode.PAYMENTCODE" class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
    <label>{{mode.PAYMENTNAME}}</label>
    <input type="text" v-model="mode.amount">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Bal Amt</label>
    <input type="text" :value="balAmt">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hey here  amount: {
        "SW": 0,
        "BB": 0,
        "WE": 0
      } you are defining statically but wehat if I got 4 input fields from json data?